# jQuery coordinated toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a container div with 2 inner divs (upper and lower). When I click on upper, it should toggle to unhide a div beneath it. At the same time I want to toggle hide the lower div, so as to keep the container height constant. Both divs - the one I toggle to hide and the one to unhide - have identical measures, but still the effect is not smooth at all (there appears to be a shaking at the beginning).

Is there any way to avoid this or do I need another way to achieve my desired result?

BTW: overflow hidden on some elements won't work for what I am trying to accomplish.

EDIT: Sorry, did not post code because it's pretty simple.

```
$("#ct").click(function () {
  $("#subcv").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
  $("#subph").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GhAM4/)

Comment: Please post your code and what you've tried.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Comment: Added code - it's really basic which is why I did not include it.

Comment: Looks fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/uzv8B/4/. If my fiddle doesn't match what you're actually doing, please post a better one.

Comment: I also tried this fiddle, with a container DIV instead of a button, it also looks good: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/uzv8B/5/

Comment: Well actually Barmar it's exactly what I mean (although the effect in your case appears less grave). You should notice the shaking at the beginning. http://jsfiddle.net/GhAM4/

Comment: @Barmar, there appears to be a 1px shift down at the bottom while the animation is running.  I think that's what the OP is trying to get rid of.  It looks like maybe the DIV that is appearing is maybe taking a 1px space at the top instead of being on top of the below.  Did you try setting an absolute position so that the first DIV is physically on top of the other?

Comment: The 1px shift becomes stronger when surrounded by a couple of divs (not sure why). I have a page where it changes 3-6 pixels. @CodeChimp: Absolute won't work in my example, although I will try to play around with it to see if it works in other cases.

Comment: I think the answer is that the two DIVs, by default, as set to display as inline blocks and not on top of one another.  I think the answer lies in setting the CSS right to make the DIVs display all in one spot on the page.  Unfortunately I am no CSS wizard, so I would have to do the same googling you would.

Comment: please check my full edited answer

Answer (score 0):

add a `position:absolute;` to the `div`s and `z-index:2;` to the green one (`#subcv`). then make only the green one move, and leave the red `div` static [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/uzv8B/6/).

full code

### html

```
<button id="ct">Click here</button>
<div id="subcv"></div>
<div id="subph"></div>
```

### css

```
#subcv, #subph {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    position:absolute;
}
#subcv {
    background-color: green;
    display:none;
    z-index:2;
}
#subph {
    background-color: red;
}
```

### jquery

```
$("#ct").click(function () {
    $("#subcv").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

your problem was that the `div`s were both on the page, one after another, so the top one lowered the bottom one by `1px`(if you used only `Toggle` it would be `50px). sorry if this part is unclear.

Comment: As I said in the comments above - absolute doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @oliver13 oh i didnt see that can you please explain why not? since this is case-dependent, there may be a specific workaround.